# Connecting a Pi to a Projector via RS232

Tags: serial

I have recently purchased a projector, and on the back, there is a Round RS232 port. After [a quick google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=control%20projector%20serial%20port), I found [this document](http://www.vivitek.co.uk/pdfs/Projector%20Serial%20Command%20D9.pdf) which seems to describe a protocol that MIGHT (I'll need to do more research) be used to control the projectors functions, such as (what i'm interested in manipulating):

- Power On/Off
- Select Source (VGA/HDMI in my case)
- Volume +/-/mute
- Keystone +/-

But, I don't have any experience of Serial Programming, so I was wondering, what sort of circuitry would be appropriate to connect a Raspberry Pi's GPIO pins to the projectors RS232 Port?

Also, any information on libraries for reading from and writing to the serial port would be good?

I have tried Googling around, and have found a few resources, but I am not too sure on what I am looking at. Are there any nice, concise tutorials that should:

1. How to wire a Raspi to a Serial Device safely
2. How to write a program that can interact with the Serial device

**ADDITIONAL**

I have done a bit more searching, and I have discovered that the input labelled RS232 on the back of the projector is a 3 Pin Mini Din Port. On this, I am also unsure which is the Tx, Rx, and Gnd, so if anyone has any help on that front, that would be brilliant

**MANY YEARS LATER**

*(I have opted not to list this as an answer, as its slightly out of scope for the original question, and I didn't want to irk others looking for an RS232 solution)*

Almost 4 years have gone by since I asked this, and I thought I would share my simpler solution.

I simply attached a 38 khz Infrared Transmitter (and Receiver for configuration), and then used LIRC to send the commands, which could be invoked as a script from wherever (PHP, Python, Java). This was so much easier to migrate than having to re-wire/re-code the Pi when I broke the first projector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you want to mess about with the GPIO UART port, your best bet would be to use a USB→Serial adapter. I'd strongly recommend trying to find one with a chipset by [FTDI](http://www.ftdichip.com/); you pay a little more for these, but they just work. Plug it in, and a serial port called something like `/dev/ttyUSB0` will appear.

For talking to the serial port, you have lots of options. [pySerial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/index.html) might be a good one. Install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install python-serial
```

Here's some (untested) code that might make it work:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', baudrate=9600, bytesize=EIGHTBITS, 
                    parity=PARITY_NONE, stopbits=STOPBITS_ONE)
ser.write("~AI" + chr(0x0d))    # select Auto Image mode
ser.close
```

This may send an unwanted newline to the projector. But I hope you get the idea about how to send the other commands.

Answer (score 5):

RS232 isn't a protocol. It's about *how* the protocol is transmitted/received.

Importantly the voltage levels are not compatible with the 0-3.3V of the RPi UART.

The good news is that there are chips to make this conversion easier [MAX3232](http://www.maximintegrated.com/datasheet/index.mvp/id/1068)

Comment: Ah, thank you. Since this is not something that a Pi does naturally, I shall take this question over to the electronics site (unless someone would like to move it)