# Serial RS232 Raspberry FTDI chip USB to RS232

Tags: python, serial

1. Circumstances 
   I am running my Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+ with Raspberry Pi OS.
   I use a FTDI chip serial cable adapter USB to RS232.
   https://www.amazon.com.mx/gp/product/B081PP3ZM4/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o09_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1
   I followed the instructions on following link: 
   https://notebook.chaopricha.com/?p=3
   The following Python script showed that the FTDI serial adapter is found on

   `/dev/ttyUSB0`

   Here the script to detect the ports:

```
ports = glob.glob('/dev/tty[A-Za-z]*')
for port in ports:
  print(port)
```

2. Target 
   Turn on and off a BenQ Projector that should work with following commands:
   Function Type Operation ASCII
   Write:      Power On    `<CR>*pow=on#<CR>`

   Write:      Power Off   `<CR>*pow=off#<CR>`

   Read:       Power Status    `<CR>*pow=?#<CR>`

   All BenQ ASCII commands can be found on:
   https://business-display.benq.com/content/dam/bb/en/product/projector/corporate/lh770/quick-start-guide/lh770-rs232-control-guide-0-windows7-windows8-winxp.pdf
   I used another small Python script to run a test (turning on projector):

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0")    
ser.baudrate = 9600                     
ser.write('<CR>*pow=off#<CR>\r')        
ser.read(ser.inWaiting())               
# You could also use ser.readline() to read but need to know # lines.
ser.close()
```

3. Problem 
   `ser.write('<CR>*pow=off#<CR>\r')`  shows following error:
   `TypeError: unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes: '<CR>*pow=off#<CR>\r'`  
   After some internet and Stackoverflow research (see links below disclaimer)
   I tried following commands **without success:**
   `ser.write(b'*pow=off#\r')`  shows no error but also no reaction, as well as:

```
    ser.write(str(b).encode("<CR>*pow=off#<CR>"))
```

Could anybody help me to understand how the strings `<CR>*pow=on#<CR>` and `<CR>*pow=off#<CR>` must be written, in order to help the python serial module’s command ser.write to interpret them correctly?

4. Disclaimer 
   I have to admit I barley know anything about Unicode and ASCII commands, please have pactions with me. 
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36613079/pyserial-sending-unicode-string-as-a-byte-array
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10268518/python-string-to-unicode
   [Connecting a Pi to a Projector via RS232](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/12293/connecting-a-pi-to-a-projector-via-rs232)

Comment: This is a simple Python programming problem, not Pi specific. You really should do some basic python courses. You are over complicating the issue. Just use normal strings with \n or \r.

Comment: To be honest, this is not a quiet helpful comment. Actually, I wrote a "normal" string (whatever that means) with \r  - ser.write('<CR>*pow=off#<CR>\r')
but this is showing no reaction (Power on does neither). If your intention is to help please help me with the code line which you think should work.

Comment: Forget  <CR> and use normal return characters \r. All the stuff about Unicode and byte strings is irrelevant. Also as you appear to be a beginner forget Python2 (which is obsolete) and use python3 which supports Unicode by default .

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I wrote following lines and ran them with Python3:
import serial
ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0")    # Open named port
ser.baudrate = 9600                     # Set baud rate to 9600
ser.write('*pow=on#\r')        # send command string
ser.close()

Unfortunately following error appliers:
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 63, in to_bytes
    raise TypeError('unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes: {!r}'.format(seq))
TypeError: unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes: '*pow=on#\r'

Comment: I also tried ser.write('\r*pow=on#\r') and substituded all <CR> but return is also:                     Traceback ():
  File "serial_interf_config.py", line 4, in <module>
    ser.write('\r*pow=on#\r')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 532, in write
    d = to_bytes(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 63, in to_bytes
    raise TypeError('unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes: {!r}'.format(seq))
TypeError: unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes: '\r*pow=on#\r'